# Division by null in MVEL returns false. What's the logic behind this?

Tags: mvel

```
public class MvelTest {
    @Test
    public void testNullDivision() {
        String expression = "2 / null";
        Serializable compiledExpression = MVEL.compileExpression(expression, new ParserContext());
        Object value = MVEL.executeExpression(compiledExpression);
        System.out.print(value); // false!
    }
}
```

Division by null returns false in MVEL. But why?
mvel2-2.1.3.Final

Answer (score 0):

If you actually debug this in Mvel API classes, they are explicitly returning `false` for this particular case.

If Mvel can fix this, it will be good. But this same issue is also encountered, so what we did, we created some intelligence before executing the expression, we modified the expression and included "IF" condition to check for the fields that are null and having operator as `/` or `*`, the return `null`.